# Match two word in arbitrary order using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have spent some time learning Regular Expression, but I still don't understand how the following trick works to **match two words in different order**.

```
import re
reobj = re.compile(r'^(?=.*?(John))(?=.*?(Peter)).*$',re.MULTILINE)

string = '''
John and Peter
Peter and John
James and Peter and John
'''
re.findall(reobj,string)
```

---

result

```
[('John', 'Peter'), ('John', 'Peter'), ('John', 'Peter')]
```

[image]

( https://www.regex101.com/r/qW4rF4/1)

I know the `(?=.* )` part is called `Positive Lookahead`, but how does it work in this situation?

Any explanation?

Comment: There are so many explanations of how lookaheads work. Maybe you should read a few of them instead of asking us to write *another one* just for you. (In other words: This is a very basic question about a well-documented and generally well-explained topic. I appreciate that the feature is not immediately apparent to a beginner, yet there is no lack of explanation on every possible level of technicality.)

Comment: I have read some tutorials about the `Positive Lookahead`, but I don't remember anything that explained this. May you provide me some useful links?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thanks, but I had read that page a few times. But still have no clue how it can match in arbitrary order.

Comment: `.*$` part is unnecessary.. @Aaron it that page, there is a statement like `They do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.`

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj , this looks more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just does not match in any arbitrary order.Capturing here is being done by `.*` which consumes anything which comes its way.The `positive lookahead` makes an assertion .You have two `lookaheads` .They are independent of each other.Each makes an assertion one word.So finally your regex works like:

1)`(?=.*?(John))`===String should have a `John`.Just an assertion.Does not consume anything

2)`(?=.*?(Peter))`===String should have a `Peter`.Just an assertion.Does not consume anything

3)`.*`===Consume anything if assertions have passed

So you see the order does not matter here.,what is imp is that `assertions should pass`.

Comment: Thanks vks, I kind of starting to grasp the meaning.

Comment: @Aaron `assertions` are standalone.Then do not verify order.Hope you are not confused and clearer about what's goin on here

Comment: reduce to  `(?=.*John)(?=.*Peter).*`

Comment: @HartmutPfarr ? Would be faster